# Overflow hidden makes img goes down and clipped

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to code **[this page](http://www.bramalodz.pl/prob/)**.

I don't know how to solve the problem, but it seems that `overflow:hidden` of `#bigf` makes image go down and clipped. How to make all those divs inside `#bigf` fits nicely in one horizontal line? Thank you.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta name="Description" content="desc">
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2" />
<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="top">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Name</h1>
    </div>
</div> 

<div id="bigf">
<div class="container">
<img src="hydraulik.png" class="hydra">

<div class="sm1">
<div class="textsec">SOMETHING</div>
<div class="textsec">IS SAID HERE</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body {
font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

#wrap {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #fff;
}

#top {
height:60px;
}

.container {
width:1160px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#bigf {
height:380px;
background: url(bf.jpg) right no-repeat black;
overflow:hidden;
}

.textsec {
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
display: inline-block;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: 600;
padding: 10px 25px;
outline: 2px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
text-shadow: 2px 3px 0px #000;
margin: 0px 0px 10px;
float:right;
font-size:26px;
}

.hydra {
margin-left:25px;
float:left;
}

.sm1 {
margin-top:150px;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you would like it to render? As it does with or without the `overflow`?

Comment: Actually what output you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `clearfix` to the `#bigf .container`.

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

And add the class to the container.

```
<div class="container cf"></div>
```

You have floated elements inside there so I recommend you to read the following : [What is Clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: You should mark this as answer for future viewers, @restless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following code in your css:

```
.hydra {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

No need to remove `overflow:hidden` just use   `vertical-align: top;`. so that the persons image and text will be aligned to top as expected.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Hey it has nothing to do with overflow hidden. 
The Image of the man jumps down because of `div.sm1` the divs in there are floating and messing with the box model.

Depending of what you want to achieve you can give .sm1 a fixed max-width (container size - image size) and let it float right, too. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `container` styles with the below code.

```
.container {
  width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  display: flex;
}
```